# Decimal to Binary without using in-built functions (like parseInt, Math.pow), etc

Tags: java

I need to create a program to take an input and convert it into binary output. I cannot use in-built functions such as (parseInt, Math.pow, etc.) to do this. I am stuck and need help. This is what I have so far, spread out across 2 java files.

Driver class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Driver {

    public Driver(){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Driver drive = new Driver();

        // scanner to read in data from the user
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // instance of the solver class
        Solver mySolver = new Solver();

        // read in the first number
        System.out.print("Enter a number to convert to binary: ");
        char [] val1 = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();

        // call solver class method to obtain the number of bits
        int numBits = mySolver.howManyBits(val1);

        // use the number of bits and the input to get the binary representation 
        char [] binaryVal1 = mySolver.stringToBinary(val1, numBits);

        // print the results
        System.out.println(new String(binaryVal1));

        // read in the arithmetic expression
        System.out.print("Enter an arithmetic expression to convert to binary: ");
        char [] val2 = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();

        // call the solver class to solve the expression
        char [] result2 = mySolver.solveExpression(val2);

        // print the results
        System.out.println(new String(result2));

        scanner.close();
    }

}
```

Solver class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solver{

    private int[] powersOf2;

    public Solver() {
        // Constructor method 
        int numPowersOf2 = 16;
        powersOf2 = new int[numPowersOf2];
        int exponent=1;

        for(int count = 1; count <= numPowersOf2; count++){
            exponent *= 2;
            powersOf2[count] = exponent;
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Main method for Solver class
        Solver solve = new Solver();
    }

    public int howManyBits(char[] val1) {
        // howManyBits method

        int decimal = Integer.parseInt(new String(val1));
        int logValue = (int) (Math.log(decimal)/Math.log(2));
        int numBits = 0;

        // Condition block to return number of bits.

        if (logValue <= 3) {
            numBits = 4;
        }
        else if (logValue <=7 && logValue > 3) {
            numBits = 8;
        }
        else if (logValue <=15 && logValue > 7) {
            numBits = 16;
        }

        System.out.println("Bits: " + numBits);

        return numBits;
    }

    public char[] stringToBinary(char[] val1, int numBits) {
        // stringToBinary method

        int decimalNumber = Integer.parseInt(new String(val1));
        char[] binaryVal1 = new char[numBits];

        int remainder = 0;

        for (int count = 0; decimalNumber > 0; count++) {

            remainder = decimalNumber % 2;  
            decimalNumber /= 2;
            char[] place = String.valueOf(remainder).toCharArray();
            binaryVal1[count] = place[count];
            System.out.println(binaryVal1[count]);
        }

        return binaryVal1;
    }

    public char[] twosComplement(char[] val1){
        return val1;

    }

    public char[] solveExpression(char[] val2) {
        // solveExpression method
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: What, in particular, are you stuck with?

Comment: I'm stuck with the powersOf2 method, which is supposed to return the power of 2 up to 16th. Also, I need to find out how many bits the binary number would require, I think my log function is good for that, not sure. I am checking out some of the binary code that is posted down here to see if I can figure it out. I need to do binary addition/subtraction after that. :| awkward situation.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am quite confused about what do you mean by "built-in functions". In that case, is `println` one of them? or `Scanner.nextInt`? I think the word "built-in function" is not very clear. I think it maybe means the functions that has the word `int`.

My idea is that you continuously divide the decimal number by 2 and store the remainder. And then you display the remainders in reverse order. That means you are probably going to use a `Stack`. This is the best method I can think of:

```
Stack<Integer> remainders = new Stack<> ();
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
int decimalNumber = s.nextInt();

while (decimalNumber >= 2) {
    remainders.push(decimalNumber % 2);
    decimalNumber /= 2;
}

remainders.push(decimalNumber);

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder ();
int size = remainders.size();
for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
    builder.append(remainders.pop());
}

System.out.println(builder);
```

P.S. Technically, functions are routines that are not in ny classes. Methods must be in one class. Which means in this case you can just use `Integer.toBinaryString`!

Just kidding, I know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you have learned about bit manipulation yet, then you can find the rightmost bit by doing a binary AND with 1 (`x & 1`), then right-shift the value using the unsigned right-shift operator (`x >>> 1`), and keep doing it until number is 0.
See The Oracle Java Tutorials [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) or the Wikipedia [Bitwise operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Depending on whether you're allowed to use the `StringBuilder` class, here are two versions:

```
// Using StringBuilder
public static String toBinary(int number) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    do {
        buf.append((number & 1) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
        number >>>= 1;
    } while (number != 0);
    return buf.reverse().toString();
}

// Using character array
public static String toBinary(int number) {
    char[] buf = new char[32];
    int i = buf.length;
    do {
        buf[--i] = (number & 1) == 0 ? '0' : '1';
        number >>>= 1;
    } while (number != 0);
    return new String(buf, i, buf.length - i);
}
```

Of course, you'll first have to parse a string to an integer, which is simple enough:

```
public static int toInt(String text) {
    if (text.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int num = 0;
    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        num = num * 10 + c - '0';
    }
    return num;
}
```

You can then combine them:

```
public static String toBinary(String text) {
    return toBinary(toInt(text));
}
```